# Add border to video, maintaing aspect ratio, and insert subtitles in the border

Tags: video, subtitles, aspect

I have an MKV wrapped 1920x800 video and a sidecar .srt subtitle file. I want to convert the video to 1920 x 1080 and add black border on top and bottom while keeping the original aspect ratio. I also want to insert the subtitles on the black border.

I have an idea on how to insert the subtitles, but I'm not sure how to add the border. I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to do this all in one pass so that I lose at little quality as possible.

Comment: What video editing tools are you using.  This is very easily done with Adobe Premiere Pro, Davinci Resolve, Final Cut Pro X, and even Blender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a free command line tool to do this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf pad=1920:1080:0:140,subtitles=filename.srt -crf 20 -c:a copy out.mkv
```

The [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#subtitles-1) filter accepts ASS styling [parameters](http://fileformats.wikia.com/wiki/SubStation_Alpha), such as font size and margins.